# How to get graphic attribute keys?

Tags: javascript, arcgis

```
GLayer = new esri.layers.GraphicsLayer();
var graphic = new esri.Graphic(point, symbol);
name = "test";                  
graphic.setAttributes({"name" : name});
GLayer.add(graphic);
```

I created a graphic layer. Graphics are added to the graphics layer.
The graphic consists of points and symbols.
I created an attribute in the graphic.
How do you get the key of all the attributes of the graphic?
or Is it possible to know the presence or absence of a specific key in the attribute of graphic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Read the documentation before posting please](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-Graphic.html). It's `graphic.attributes`.

Instead of reading the docs you could also have used `console.log(graphic)` to dump the object to the console where you could have found that it has an `attributes` parameter, or you could have used debugging tools to set a breakpoints on one of the lines and inspected the `graphic` object to view all its keys. Please try to do your own research and investigation first.